# Buffered writer writes memory trash on text file

Tags: java, int, text-files, jtextfield, bufferedwriter

My buffered writer is writting some randomly trash in my txt file. I use int  `nodes = Integer.valueOf(NODES_TEXT_FIELD.getText());` to store the value of one TextField that should only accept ints.

this is my writer:

```
 private static void writeOnFile(BufferedWriter writer, int nodes){

           try {
               System.out.println(nodes);
               System.out.println("Last check before write");
                writer.write(nodes);
                System.out.println(nodes);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to write data on file");
                e.printStackTrace();            
        }      
       }
```

My output:

```
2
Last check before write
2
```

and in the text file I found: '?' (which changes to another memory trash depending on what number you input

Anybody has any Idea of what might be wrong? I stuck here for 5 hours until now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(int)) writes a character .

> Writes a single character. The character to be written is contained in the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order bits are ignored.
>
> Parameters:
>
> c - int specifying a character to be written

You can use [Writer#write(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(java.lang.String)):

```
writer.write(String.valueOf(nodes));
```

Comment: Thanks, that was brilliant and fast.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Writer wr = new FileWriter("thefileToWriteTo.txt");
wr.write( String.valueOf(nodes) );
wr.close();
```

you can always extract the writing into a loop if that is what you are doing with your nodes or some kind of escaping, it would be more helpful if you explain what is it that you are actually trying to achieve by writing this to a file, as we might advise you on that.